# getting error while building signed apk

Tags: android, android-proguard

- Warning:library class android.content.res.XmlResourceParser extends or implements program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.content.Intent depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
- Warning:library class android.content.IntentFilter depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.content.res.ColorStateList depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.graphics.drawable.ScaleDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
- Warning:library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:library class android.view.LayoutInflater depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
- Warning:there were 32 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
- Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

Comment: Do you have proguard enabled? You may need to add some lines to your proguard file then

Comment: yes I make it enable, but unable to understand what rules i need to add.

Comment: Add -ignorewarnings to your proguard file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following lines to your proguard file

```
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontnote org.xmlpull.v1.**
-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
```

I'm not 100% sure, it's best to just try it out yourself. The first line might be enough.

Comment: thanks but after building apk its swing "App not installed" during installation

Comment: You might have the debug version of the app already installed on your phone. Delete that first.